# How to change the default markup in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

When I write `<htm` and press on the promtp by Enter, Sublime Text gives hypertext markup such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How I can to change this code, i.e. add some tags and spaces?

Comment: I think that's called a snippet.  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Answer (score 1):

This is triggered by a [snippet](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html) in the HTML package. To edit it, you'll first need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) from Package Control. Then, open the Command Palette and type in ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options. Select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource → HTML → Snippets → html.sublime-snippet` to open the snippet. Edit the snippet as you wish (see the link above for options), then hit save. The file will be saved as `Packages/HTML/Snippets/html.sublime-snippet`, where the `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

Keep in mind that this file will always override the identically-named file in the `HTML.sublime-package` archive. This means that your saved file will not be upgraded when you upgrade Sublime Text.